# How do I convert standard emojis to equivalent images from the SoftBank 2008 set when a user makes a post?

Tags: php, image, gif, emoji, user-generated-content

I have a simple website where users can post threads of images and text.
However, I don't want to use emojis because they vary too much across platforms, among other issues.

My solution to this problem is to automatically convert any emoji someone types in a post to an equivalent gif image, specifically one from the [SoftBank 2008 emoji](https://emojipedia.org/softbank/2008) set. Supposedly, the emojis would all be stored as a single GIF image on the server. I couldn't find this image, but I'm just going to assume such an image is available.
(EDIT: So as @CBroe pointed out, the emojis would have to be separate GIFs, not a single GIF which contains a sheet of emojis)

So, in my server software (written in PHP), how do I convert unicode emojis in a user-generated piece of text to static GIF images?

Comment: Either your individual GIFs would have to be named in a way that corresponds to the unicode codepoints of the emojis ( -> `U+1F60A` -> `1F60A.gif`), or you would have to create a "translation table" for that (so that you can go look up that `U+1F60A` corresponds to `arbitrary_file_name_for_this_particular_emoji.gif`)